# spring autowiring fails but appcontext resolves bean

Tags: spring, autowired

i have the following issue with spring. I have a webapp and a domain project. the domain project contains a studentService which should be injected through autowiring in a class of the webapp. I've added  and  to the appcontext.xml.

this is the class from the webapp:

```
@Component
public class JSONToDomainObjects
{

@Autowired
private StudentService studentService;

private void bindSubmissionValuesToDomainObjects(Integer userKey) throws Exception
{
 Student student =  studentService.getStudentBySlNumber(userKey);
}
}
```

then the studentservice:

```
@Service
public class StudentService
{
  ..
}
```

So once I startup my app I see that the studentService is null, but when I get the appcontext and invoke the method getBean("studentService") than a studentservice instance is returned. I use spring 3.0.5. Does anybody have a clue why the autowiring fails?

cheers,

Michael

Comment: How are you wiring your `JSONToDomainObjects` class? How do you get it?

Comment: well it finally will be called by a controller class annotated with @controller but at the moment I have a testng test that uses a filesystemxmlapplicationcontext to read in a test-application-context.xml. then I have a test that at the moment is instantiating the jsontodomainobjects through the new keyword such as: JSONToDomainObjects converter = new JSONToDomainObjects(); and then on the converter object will be invoking the method bindSubmissionValuesToDomainObjects

Comment: well perhaps you are right, what I was doing was instantiating the jsontodomainobjects class and I guess that that didn't trigger the autowiring or something. Could this theory be correct?

Comment: yup. if you call `new JSONToDomainObjects()`, no dependency injection takes place :-)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use dependency injection in your testclasses as well? Something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"appcontext.xml"})
public final class JSONToDomainObjectsTests {
    private StudentService service;

    @Autowired
    public void setService(StudentService service) {
        this.service= service;
    }

    @Test
    public void testJSONToDomain() {
        service.foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `<context:annotation-config/>` in your appcontext.xml?

Comment: And how about <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.my.package" /> ? Does the specified package include the one of StudentService?

Comment: yes it does, but i think the problem lies in the test aproach as described above